# Filtering Navigation Properties in ViewDate.ModelMetaData.Properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I'm creating custom `Editor Templates` for my classes. I'd like to filter all of the navigation properties. Is there anyway to achieve this without using naming conventions for my properties?

My Partial View looks like this:

```
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            @if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Z") || 
                property.PropertyName.Equals("thename", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                ){
                continue;
            }
            @Html.Label(property.DisplayName)
            @Html.TextBox(property.PropertyName)
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a bool flag to Display. If the flag is set to Display, then display the property with a label and textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The method I would propose to use would be to use a custom attribute on your model (the POCO). Use the attribute to flag the special properties. Before entering the loop, you can use reflection to get a `Dictionary<string, customAttribute>` where `string` is the name of a property on the model, and `customAttribute` is the custom attribute applied to the class (check for `null` to handle properties that do not have the custom attribute applied). I have attached a LinqPad script that demonstrates these concepts, and you get nice visuals to see what is happening.

```
void Main()
{

    var obj = new MyCustomClass();
    var tModel = obj.GetType(); /*in your case this will probably be ModelMetadata.ModelType as below */
    //var tModel = ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType;

    var pAttributes = tModel
        .GetProperties() /*modify the parameter to determine whether you want public fields as well etc*/
        .ToDictionary(p =>
            p.Name,
            p => ((MyCustomAttribute)p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MyCustomAttribute)))
        );

    pAttributes.Dump();

    /*I'm using this to mimic your ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties */
    var modelProperties = new[] { 
        new { PropertyName = "Age" }, 
        new { PropertyName = "Name" },
        new { PropertyName = "Height" },
        new { PropertyName = "Area" }
    }.ToList();

    foreach (var property in modelProperties)
    {
        if (pAttributes.ContainsKey(property.PropertyName) && (pAttributes[property.PropertyName]?.HasSpecialTreatment ?? false))
            Console.WriteLine("I am special: " + property.PropertyName);
        else
            Console.WriteLine(property.PropertyName);

    }

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class MyCustomClass
{
    [MyCustomAttribute(HasSpecialTreatment = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MyCustomAttribute(HasSpecialTreatment = false)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [MyCustomAttribute(HasSpecialTreatment = true)]
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public int Area { get; set; }
}

public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public bool HasSpecialTreatment = false;
}
```

A downside to this approach is that it relies on reflection, and I would much sooner use that approach to generate the template rather than to execute on the fly each time the page executes.

Which version of MVC are you using? Better approaches would be to use a ModelMetaDataProvider or a IDisplayMetadataProvider depending on the MVC version to provide the metadata early in the pipeline and simplify the programming in your View Pages.

- http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/14/creating-your-own-modelmetadataprovider-to-handle-custom-attributes/
- http://blog.emikek.com/reinstating-imetadataaware-in-asp-net-5-vnext-mvc-6/